# Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know there is lots of answer about this problem but in case what we do in  my problem.
I have try changes in java build path and  but not working.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0

Comment: The runtime needs to be at least as new as the compiler. For the list: https://www.baeldung.com/java-find-class-version - Maybe time to update the runtime jre ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your case, you're using a Java 16 JVM and trying to run code compiled with Java 17.  Use a JVM that's at least version 17 or higher to run it with.